# Overriding an input of the Exposed Views form to render a range of values

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-6, drupal-exposed-filter

In the Exposed Views form (Drupal 6, Views 2), I'd like to overwrite an input text so it render the option to choose from a range of values, something similar to this:

[image]

Or just a simple one: two text inputs with *from* and *to* labels (*min*, *max*, whatever, like a price range).

I am comfortable both with editing templates (`views-exposed-form.tpl.php` in this case) and overwritting the form output:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
        $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Filter');
    }
}
```

How can I change the defaul text input to one as described?

Comment: how to do such thing, editing the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing something similar as a template function.
You can remove the rendered output and render your own as a theming function.

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  switch($vars['form']['#id']){
    case 'views-exposed-form-VIEW_NAME-page-1':
      $vars['widgets']['filter-YOUR_FIELD']->widget = YOUR_CODE_HERE;
  }
}
```

Be sure to use dpm() from the Devel module to figure the identifiers you need to use because might be slightly different in the theme layer.